# Android Studio's logcat shows "Error inflating class EditText" on running the app in Gionee P5W having Lollipop(5.1)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-5.0-lollipop, android-5.1.1-lollipop

Here is the XML code for the **EditText** widget which is causing the error.
I think the error is due to my phone's Android version (Lollipop 5.1).

```
    <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:hint="UserName"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_border_edittext"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:id="@+id/userName"/>
```

Below is the code for the launcher activity of the app which is a login activity.
Here is the **complete xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/DFO"
        android:fontFamily="@font/dreschergroteskbtsmallsizes"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/string1"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/dreschergroteskbtsmallsizes"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#3FDDFD"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/string2"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/dreschergroteskbtsmallsizes"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#3FDDFD"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint="UserName"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_border_edittext"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:id="@+id/userName"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_border_edittext"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/password"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Save"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:fontFamily="@font/dreschergroteskbtsmallsizes"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_border_button"
        android:id="@+id/saveBtn"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:background="#DE1D1D"
            android:id="@+id/redStrip"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
            android:background="#3FDDFD"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/redStrip"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:background="#F3F333"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/redStrip"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/string3"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/dreschergroteskbtsmallsizes"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#3FDDFD"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/powered"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/dreschergroteskbtsmallsizes"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#4C4C43"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the launcher activity of the app. The app crashes on launch of this activity.
Here is the **logcat**:

```
06-13 10:20:02.321 31384-31384/com.journalfdwb.digitizedjournalmanagement E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.journalfdwb.digitizedjournalmanagement, PID: 31384
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.journalfdwb.digitizedjournalmanagement/com.journalfdwb.digitizedjournalmanagement.LoginPage}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class EditText
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class EditText
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at com.journalfdwb.digitizedjournalmanagement.LoginPage.onCreate(LoginPage.java:20)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.journalfdwb.digitizedjournalmanagement:drawable/rounded_border_edittext" (7f070078)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f070078 a=-1 r=0x7f070078}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2690)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2614)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3795)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:663)
        at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:70)
        at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:66)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:64)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:60)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createEditText(AppCompatViewInflater.java:191)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:113)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1035)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1092)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at com.journalfdwb.digitizedjournalmanagement.LoginPage.onCreate(LoginPage.java:20) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Comment: post your full logcat.. and xml file.

Comment: This is the root cause: `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.journalfdwb.digitizedjournalmanagement:drawable/rounded_border_edittext" (7f070078)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f070078 a=-1 r=0x7f070078}` Show us, how this drawable is defined.

Comment: The drawable is defined as: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#C8CACB"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>`

Comment: I used this file for adding background to the **EditText** widget and similar files for other widgets too. Would the other files cause the error too?

Comment: Also the project window shows (v24) beside the file names.